# How can I redirect before render?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build an web app using react and I kind of hit the wall.

The thing is, I don't want any users who has already logged in to access the login page.

I tried to redirect them using render method and componentDidMount method, but since the render method is called before componentDidMount, the login page flashes out before redirection.

These are my codes.

I'm using redux and firebase to control the component state and authenticate.

```
class CenterPanel extends Component {
    render() {
        const { user }=this.props;

        if(user!=null) { //this is how I tried to redirect
            return ( //
                <Redirect to='/somewhereNotHere' />
            );
        }

        return ( //this flashes out before redirection
            <div className={cx('center_panel')}>
                <div className={cx('button')}>
                    login
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { changeUserStatus }=this.props;

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
            (user) => changeUserStatus(user)
        );
    }
}
```

would appreciate any kind of advice.
Thx in advance.

Comment: try settings window.location to '/somewhereNotHere'

Comment: I've tried window.location and history. Both of them succeeded in redirection, but login page still flashes out before redirection. I want users who has already logged in to have absolutely no access to login page.

Comment: just return `null` instead of the `<div ... />` tree when user is not null.  But redirect before returning null...

Comment: where do you get `user` prop value ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the props `user` is undefined before you call `onAuthStateChanged`

If it is right, you can control your component by three `user` values. undefined, null, user value.

```
render() {
        const { user }=this.props;

        if(user === undefined){
            return null; //or Loading component
        }

        if(user!=null) { //this is how I tried to redirect
            return ( //
                <Redirect to='/somewhereNotHere' />
            );
        }

        return ( //this flashes out before redirection
            <div className={cx('center_panel')}>
                <div className={cx('button')}>
                    login
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thx! solved the issue! The idea of dividing user status into undefined, null, user obj is working perfectly.

Comment: Quick Note: After react-router-dom 6v Redirect got replaced by Navigate.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
if(user && user!==null) { //this is how I tried to redirect
     return <Redirect to='/somewhereNotHere' />  //Make sure you have imported Redirect from correct package i.e. react-router-dom
}else{
     return ( //this flashes out before redirection
            <div className={cx('center_panel')}>
                <div className={cx('button')}>
                    login
                </div>
            </div>
     );
}
```

**[Another way](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md)** of doing this is in `Routes` itself,

```
<Route exact path="/your_Path_to_component" render={() => (
  user ? ( //get the user data as you are passing as props to CenterPanel component
    <Redirect to="/somewhereNotHere"/>
  ) : (
    <CenterPanel />
  )
)}/>
```

In this way no need to pass `user` as `props` to `CenterPanel` component as well as no need to write any redirection logic in `CenterPanel` component.

Comment: Late comer here, to put it in the router might be viewed as breaking the principle of encapsulation as if in the future you will add more complex validations prior to rendering the router in the main index file and the component will be coupled.
On the other hand, the entire concpet of react that components in render method are responsible for redirect is against many other OOP principles. 
First method you showed is better in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by conditioning the view

```
user && <div>...</div>
```

the content of the page will only show up if the user is truthy (authenticated).